# Different contact form for different contacts in joomla 1.6

Tags: joomla

In joomla 1.6 we can easily assign the default contact form to a contact. But i need to make some new contact form (which is contain some specified field what i need).

So the steps of this i think:

1. make a copy of the default_form.php, and modify as i like..
2. make some change in the database
3. **How can i assign my new_form.php to my contact?**

Answer (score 1):

I found the Contact Enhanced Component very handy for this. It can be found the Joomla Extension Directory. Unfortunately it's not free, but there may be alternatives in the TED.

Answer (score -1):

This is easier if you create some contact categories, and assign a contact form to each member. Like this you can group people and assign a contact form for each.